# How to fix Assertion '__pos <= size()' failed.?

Tags: c++, c++14

I know this question's been asked a lot of times here but I don't seem to get exactly what this error means.

I have this code which wants to take a string and make it all lowercase.

```
std::string minusculas(std::string a){
  std::string mayus = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  std::string lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  std::string final = "";
  for(int x = 0; x< a.size(); x++){
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    if(mayus.find(a[x]) != std::string::npos){
      final += lower[lower.find(a[x])];
    }else{
      final+= a[x];
    }
  }
return final;
```

I know this isn't the most optimal way to go around the problem but when I write a string with any character in uppercase this happens:

`/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:1067: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::reference std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::reference = char&; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]: Assertion '__pos <= size()' failed.`

This doesn't happen when the string is all lowercase.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. When `a[x]` is in `mayus`, you are looking for it in `lower` and use this index without checking. But when it is in `mayus`, it cannot be in `lower`.

Comment: Use [std::tolower](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower).

Comment: Simpler, faster, shorter, and correct (for SBCSs): `{ for (auto& c : a) c = std::tolower((unsigned char)c); return a; }`

Answer (score 0):

Just a little mistake => searching a mayus in lower. If you get this kind of error just insert some cout in your code and you will detect the problem ;)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

std::string minusculas(std::string a){
  std::string mayus = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  std::string lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  std::string final = "";
  for(int x = 0; x< a.length(); x++){
    if(mayus.find(a[x]) != std::string::npos){
        // detect that with lower you get a wrong index (out of range index)
        cout << "MAYUS " << mayus.find(a[x])<< endl;
      final += lower[mayus.find(a[x])];
    }else{
      final += a[x];
    }
  }
return final;
}

int main()
{
    string res = minusculas("tEest");
    cout<<res;
    return 0;
}
```